# iterate over subpart of dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Are the elements in a dictionary in a particular order in python?

I would like to do something like:

```
for i in dict:
    for j in dict[e:]:
```

I get errors running this code. How would you implement two for loops the second of which would run only thru the elements which are after the element from the second loop??

**Edit** as requested:
the dictionary is of the

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, sum = 0):
        self.sum = sum
```

I would like to multiply all the numbers with all the others and add the results for each Num to the member sum.
Example:

```
dict = {1: Num(), 2: Num(), 3: Num()}
```

The desired for loops would do:

```
dict[1].sum += 1*2
dict[2].sum += 1*2
dict[1].sum += 1*3
dict[3].sum += 1*3
dict[2].sum += 2*3
dict[3].sum += 2*3
```

I need for loops for that

**Or equvialent for this:**

```
for i in dict:
    for j in dict[e:]:
```

Is there something like **HashableDict**?

Comment: Python dictionaries do not have a fixed order, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.

If you want to partition your dict in smaller chunks of equal size, you can do so via `keys()`:

```
keys = d.keys()
for key in keys[5:]:
    print key, d[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries don't have order/index. You can use an OrderedDict or just list the dictionary items first.

```
mydict.items() #returns your dictionary in list for with tuples(key,value) with order
```

So for you,

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self, sum = 0):
        self.sum = sum

    def _add(self,num):
        self.sum += num

mydict = {1:Num(), 2:Num(), 3:Num()}

for key in mydict:
    mydict[key]._add(sum([key*otherkey for otherkey in mydict if otherkey != key]))

for key,value in mydict.items():
    print key,value.sum
```

Output:

```
 1 5
 2 8
 3 9
```

Comment: I added what I would like to do, coul you please edit accordingly?

Comment: @gen Edited also added to Num

Answer (score 0):

Python has an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), where the elements are ordered based on insertion time.

You can convert your dict into an ordered dict by:

```
orderedDict = OrderedDict(sorted(yourDict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that it is quite clear what you want to do, you rather seem to want to combine the keys.

```
import itertools
d = {1: Num(), 2: Num(), 3: Num()}
for i, j in itertools.product(dict.keys(), dict.keys()):
    if i != j:
        dict[i].sum += i*j
        dict[j].sum += i*j
```

Comment: thanks it is really good, however it iterates over cases where i = j, how could that be avoided? @glglgl

Comment: add a conditional? if i==j: continue